# What's the best approach in Android for disabling all peripheral ports for certain applications?

Tags: applications, usb, aosp

My company has their own Android tablets created by an OEM partner and we are using custom ROM based on Android 11. The stakeholders have a strange requirement now. They want to allow only our applications (identified by bundle id) to have access to printers and bar code scanners connected to the peripheral ports. Users are allowed to install any application of their choice from the Playstore and they will function normally but when it comes to printing or scanning via peripheral ports, it shouldn't work.

We have full control over the AOSP build and can do whatever we want to ensure above requirements are met. I have no clue where to start and appreciate some help.

Comment: How about MDM software

Answer (score 0):

Remove the drivers for any OTHER peripherals from the linux kernel used in your AOSP build..... I don't know how is it done etc refer to the linux documentation as well as AOSP documentation to figure it out

Comment: I dont think that will work. Drivers are needed for our own apps to perform printing and scanning.